# Failure to launch Atom on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: error-handling, 22.04, atom

I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and installed Atom following this [post](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-atom-text-editor-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/). Upon launching from the icon, the window opens but remains blank and then crashes within few seconds. On terminal I get:

```
$ atom
/usr/bin/atom: line 195: 30027 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) nohup "$ATOM_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$ATOM_HOME/nohup.out" 2>&1
[30027:0429/141844.105294:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(439)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
--2022-04-29 14:18:44--  https://atom.io/crash_reports
Resolving atom.io (atom.io)... 20.119.16.4
Connecting to atom.io (atom.io)|20.119.16.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 204 No Content
2022-04-29 14:18:45 (0.00 B/s) - ‘/dev/fd/4’ saved [0]


Unexpected crash report id length
Failed to get crash dump id.
Report Id: 
--2022-04-29 14:18:45--  https://atom.io/crash_reports
Resolving atom.io (atom.io)... 20.119.16.4
Connecting to atom.io (atom.io)|20.119.16.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 204 No Content
2022-04-29 14:18:47 (0.00 B/s) - ‘/dev/fd/4’ saved [0]


Unexpected crash report id length
Failed to get crash dump id.
Report Id:
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Does this happen also if you install through other sources? I mean, have you tried the deb package in their website (https://atom.io/) or maybe installing via flatpak?

Comment: You probably manually added the Atom repo, which still uses Atom 1.60 (on the Electron 9 framework) The snap package is probably more up to date. Electron 9 is end of life. Also see https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/23608#issuecomment-1096647208

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. Atom worked after uninstalling it `sudo apt purge atom` and installing it with snap `sudo snap install atom --classic`

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem (On Kubuntu 22.04). In my case the problem was
fixed by executing Atom with the `--no-sandbox` parameter.
Like this:

`atom --no-sandbox`

I think it's a problem with Electron, because a similar error occurred
in another Electron-App.
I took the solution from this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/ebkr/r2modmanPlus/issues/735
(I know that this isn't atom, but this has shown up if I searched the error)

In my case it's also showing some errors and asking me for the user-password, I just canceled it and closed the errors and Atom just worked flawlessly.

I hope that helps.

Comment: `atom --in-process-gpu` often also fixes the issue and is more safe (https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/23608)

Comment: @Bart in my case, I was not able to launch Atom, after switching from Internal Intel to Nvidia GPU. Your comment solved my issue

Comment: @qba-dev: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04. I found that @Bart comment overcame the reported issue, i.e. type in commandline `atom --in-process-gp` instead of `atom`. However, this meant that the Atom application will still not work when the `atom.desktop` icon is clicked on.

I found that Atom installed via `Flatpak` worked. The installation commands used were:

```
sudo apt install flatpak
sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
sudo flatpak install flathub io.atom.Atom
```

To run atom via commandline I typed:

```
flatpak run io.atom.Atom
```

Also clicking on the `atom.desktop` icon worked.

Having said the above, I also need to highlight here that the **[Atom is sunsetting](https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/)**. Consequently, it is **best to stop using Atom moving forward and start migrating to other text editors to build software**.

To uninstall Atom via Flatpak:

```
sudo flatpak remove io.atom.Atom
```